# Blink/Alert in Taskbar for c++

Tags: c++, windows, taskbar

I'm writing my own class to create and handle a progress/overlayicons for a programs taskbar icon.

I'm using the [ITaskbarList3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391692(v=vs.85).aspx) for Windows 7/higher to do this. I can now create a progress or overlayicons, but what I'm missing is the alert/blink effect, that appears if a program wants to get the users attention (e.g. if you have to confirm admin rights and are working on a different tab).

I do not mean the pause/error-indicators for a progress, I need the blinking orange effect, and i wasn't able to find something until now.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [FlashWindowEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679347(v=vs.85).aspx). See the doc on [FLASHWINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679348(v=vs.85).aspx) - you can start flashing, stop flashing and specify flashing parameters.

For continuous blinking until the user clicks on the window the code is like this:

```
FLASHWINFO fi;
fi.cbSize = sizeof(FLASHWINFO);
fi.hwnd = yourHwnd;
fi.dwFlags = FLASHW_ALL | FLASHW_TIMERNOFG;
fi.uCount = 0;
fi.dwTimeout = 0;
FlashWindowEx(&fi);
```